# Issue With Insert Record In Database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have table in SQL Server and then going to Visual Studio -> Server Explorer -> Add connection, my table is added successfully.

Problem is data is not inserted into SQL Server when I press a create button then not any error shown, I think the record is created but when I refresh in SQL Server Management Studio, in the table, the record is not displayed...

Table: `empls`

```
empid int primary key
empname varchar(50)
empsalary varchar(50)
empage int
```

Class:

```
[Table("empls")]
public class stdimg
{
    [Key]
    public int empid { get; set; }

    public string empname { get; set; }
    public string empsalary { get; set; }
    public int empage { get; set; }
}
```

Context class is the bridge between the database and application:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class studcontext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<stdimg> stds { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    studcontext _context = new studcontext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult InsertData()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InsertData(stdimg studs)
    {
        _context.stds.Add(studs);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.message = "data inserted successfully"; 
        return View();
    }
}
```

InsertData.cshtml:

```
@model ImageUploadUsingMvc.Models.stdimg

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "InsertData";
}

<h2>InsertData</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>stdimg</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.empname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.empname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.empsalary, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.empsalary, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empsalary, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.empage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.empage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.empage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I already created a database in SQL Server Management Studio, and adding a database in my project successfully. But when I click on the create button, the code does not generate any errors, but after a refresh of my database, the record is not shown....

I put the `viewbag.message="record successfully"` message not display and record not display in SQL Server?

Can someone please help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what I m doing wrong can anyone suggest??

Comment: When you debug - does your `InsertData` get called, and are the parameter values passed into it OK?

Comment: maybe your connection string is wrong, what do you get if you call `_context.stds.ToList()`

Comment: @JamieD77 ```_context.stds.ToList()``` I put this index method and all record should be displayed?? but when I refresh my table all record not display???? can u help more which place I add to the connection string in my class???

Comment: @marc_s _context.stds.ToList() I put this index method and all records should be displayed?? but when I refresh my table all records not display???? plz help

Answer (score -1):

You not perform Post on Html.BeginForm()
Then i suggest you to create independent service to to that job